# Applied for business visa, processed by BLS as tourist visa

Tags: visas, schengen, tourist-visas

I am due to travel to Spain in about 2 weeks. I will be visiting to acquire a vacation house for my parents.
I initially applied for a short stay type C visa for business purposes. However, upon my arrival at BLS, they informed me that it will be processed under tourist visa. They didn’t take the letter of my lawyer, they just took my bank statements and business registrations plus my cover letter stating that I’m requesting for short stay visa for business purposes.

I asked the BLS employees if this is okay considering that my application form also stated for business purposes. They told me it’s alright, I have completed the documents like return ticket, hotel reservations, and travel insurance. They also took into consideration that I have lived in a Schengen country before and had residence permit which they photocopied. I also have previous stamps on my passport indicating that I travelled to Europe many times before.
They informed me that they are just strict with first time travelers and there’s no need to worry.

Just want to ask if you guys encountered the same situation?

Comment: Just for clarity, there is no distinction between Schengen business and tourist visas. There is a single 'short stay visa' that applies to all visit purposes.